# Use the definition of continuity to prove that $g$ is continuous at $x = 0$

Tags: continuity, proof-writing

Let $D$ be a subset of R containing $0$, and let $f : D → R$ be bounded on $D$ (i.e., $f(D)$ is
a bounded subset of R). Define a new function $g : D → R$ by $g(x) = xf(x)$.

(a) Use the definition of continuity to prove that $g$ is continuous at $x = 0$.

(b) Suppose $c ≠ 0$. Prove that $g$ is continuous at $c$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $c$.
(Hint: Use a theorem on continuity.)

So, I'm currently working on part a, and I know I should use an epsilon-delta definition, but I have no idea what to do with it? Do we have to use something in regards to $f$ being bounded on D, and using the axiom of completeness to show that it has a supremum and infemum, or does that go to part b? If someone could give me a general idea where to go with the two proofs, it'd be super appreciated.

Comment: $|g(x)-g(0)|=|x||f(x)|\le M|x|$. If $|x|\le \delta$... can you continue from there?

Answer (score 1):

For (a) $g$ is continuous at $a$ because $f$ is bounded so $f<M$ for some constant $M$ hence the problem reduces to proving the continuity of $Mx$ which is easy.

For (b) Assume that for $c$ not equal to $0$, $g$  is continuous at $c$ then $g/x$ is continuous(quotient of continuous functions is continuous ) on $c$ hence $f$ is continuous at $c$. If $f$ is continuous at $c$ then $g$ is continuous since product of continuous functions is continuous .